# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on success handler in ajax call jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I do ajax call and it returns correct data as printed. Here is success handler :

```
success : function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'FAIL') {
            for ( var val in response.errorsMessages) {
                var $errorLabel = $.find('#' + val.toString() + 'ErrorLabel');              
                console.log("$errorLabel=" + $errorLabel);
                $errorLabel.text(response.errorsMessages[val]);
            }
            }
        },
```

Very strange is that `$errorLabel` is found and on console I see:

```
$errorLabel=[object HTMLLabelElement]
```

Next line gives exception which is on title of this topic.

Why jQuery method `find` works well but method `text` on jQuery object is not recognized?

If `$errorLabel` is not jQuery object then how to make it so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your mistake is

```
$.find('#' + val.toString() + 'ErrorLabel');
```

You are passing something random to jQuery's build-in `find` function, which returns an unexpected result, so $errorLabel will be a JavaScript object, but not a jQuery object, and so it doesn't have a `.text()` method.
That line should simply be a call of the jQuery constructor

```
$('#' + val.toString() + 'ErrorLabel');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to

```
var $errorLabel = $('#' + val.toString() + 'ErrorLabel');
```